# Анимация увеличения текста в навигационном меню

Tags: css, css-animation

Как сделать, чтобы блоки не «плясали» при анимации увеличения текста?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

body {
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
  min-height: 800px;
  background-color: #A1A1A1;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: #3641E7;
}

.nav {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  font-size: 16px;
}

a:hover {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Practic-2</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="practic2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="practic2-media-query.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header">
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Сообщество</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Помощь</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Тогда добавьте свойство `vertical-align` элементу списка:

```
li {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;

  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

body {
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
  min-height: 800px;
  background-color: #A1A1A1;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: #3641E7;
}

.nav {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

a {
  font-size: 16px;
}

a:hover {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Practic-2</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="practic2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="practic2-media-query.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header">
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Сообщество</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Помощь</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: И чем это мне поможет? Мне нужно, чтобы блоки не плясали, когда на них наводишь мышкой, а не плавную анимацию сделать.

Comment: @Markva, может тогда и вопросе стоит это написать?

Comment: Извиняюсь, я думал проблема очевидна..

Comment: @Markva, обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 25px;
}

body {
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
  min-height: 800px;
  background-color: #A1A1A1;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: #3641E7;
}

.nav {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  font-size: 16px;
}

a:hover {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Practic-2</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="practic2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="practic2-media-query.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header">
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Сообщество</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Помощь</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```